# Confusing calculator result

Tags: calculator

I was doing some simple maths for a project when I stumbled upon an error (?) in my calculator (casio fx 991), I'll explain:

I wanted to make the next **rule of three** calculation:

$$
\frac{x}{4}=\frac{0.74}{1.7} \longrightarrow x=\frac{0.74 \cdot 4}{1.7}
$$

by putting $0.74 \cdot 4$ on the calculator, it equals to $2.96$, by now it is correct.

then, I press $\texttt{Ans} \div 1.7$ and it gives me $1.024...$ as result.

when putting this result back on the first equation, something doesn't feels right.

$$
\frac{1.024}{4}=\frac{0.74}{1.7}
$$

then, I used the Symbolab website to make sure it was right, and it was wrong, I found out $x$ should be equal to $1.74$.

what is the problem here? is it something about how calculators work? i am sure i didn't commited a mistake.

Comment: There is something wrong here ' i press Ans÷1.7 and it gives me 1.024... as result'

Comment: Clearly, $\frac {2.96}{1.7}\neq 1.024$

Comment: You somehow divided twice `2.96 / 1.7 / 1.7 ≈ 1.024`.

Comment: Seems there's another previous calculus whose result is 1.74, so **Ans** used it

Answer (score 1):

Each of the steps you did was correct, until you divided by $1.7$.  If you divide by $2.96$ by $1.7$ once, you get $1.74$ as expected.  The problem was you divided by $1.7$ twice (as dxiv mentioned in the comments above), giving you $1.024$.

Comment: now i see it, it was because it gave a fracctional answer first and i wanted it in decimals, i pressed shift+= and it counted with the last answer. Thank you and dxiv.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have pressed `=` twice in a row

Mine hidden in a cupboard  takes `0.74 × 4 =` and gives $\frac{74}{25}$ which is indeed $2.96$. (How do you turn fractions off?)

Then doing `Ans ÷ 1.7 =` gives $\frac{148}{85}$ which is $1.741176471$

But pressing `=` again gives $\frac{296}{289}$ which is $1.024221453$ as it repeats the division by $1.7$.